# Jenkins Pipeline docker login and pull the image from private registry

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have Jenkins scripted pipeline to deploy my application in EKS cluster. Here i have created 2 stages after building my application build docker image, push the docker image.

After creating docker image I'm sending my image into private registry using docker login command with user of my name let assume user1.

Here the code for jenkins file to build the docker image

```
stage('Build Docker Image') {
        container('docker') {
            sh "docker build --network=host -t my_app_image:latest ."
        }
    }
```

Here the code for jenkins file to push the docker image

```
stage('Push Docker images') {
       container('docker') {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'Artifactory', passwordVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_USER')]) {
                sh """ docker login -u  ${ARTIFACTORY_USER} private-docker-registry -p ${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}
                docker push my_app_image:latest """
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note above code Aritfactory user and password are stored jenkins credentials under the manage jenkins, if suppose in future existing user is not exists and he/she removed from current project then jenkins  not able to pull or push the image from private registry.

Then we need add one more user who joined newly into this project, under the mange jenkins credentials part, how to avoid this  and how we can use AWS role and policy to accomplish this.

can you please some guide me.

Comment: Have you tried the Docker plugin for Jenkins Pipeline? It has a global variable step method for exactly this.

Comment: Docker plugin i have but how this will pull image from the private registry we need pass authentication as well right